# How can I print numbers that has zero inside?

Tags: c, division

I wrote a program to separate digits of a given number. It separates successfully when number is composed of non zeros but when there is a number with 0 inside, it does not recognize and it does not print. What should I do? I am going insane!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int quotient (int a, int b);
int remaindar (int a, int b);

int main(void) {

int a,b,number,temp=1,divisor=10000;

printf("Enter three integers: ");
scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&number);

printf("a/b is %d , remainder is %d.\n",quotient(a,b),remaindar(a,b));

temp=number;

while (temp>=1){

        if(temp>=divisor){

            printf("%d  ", quotient(temp,divisor)); 
            temp=remaindar(temp,divisor);
            divisor=divisor/10;
        }

        else divisor=divisor/10;

}


getch();    

return 0;   
}

int quotient (int a, int b){

return a/b; 

}

int remaindar (int a, int b){

return a%b;

}
```

Comment: Don't use conio.h and getch().That's not standard C and the code may not work everywhere.

Comment: Seems ok, can you give an example of bad inputs?

Comment: explain what does a, b and number mean?

Comment: I am learning how to write functions so additionally this program takes two integers and finds the remainder and quotient by a function instead of % and /. Those are additional things. Not important.

Comment: Bad inputs are for example 5067, 6900 which has zeros inside.

Comment: These output as 5  6  7 and 6  9.

Comment: Maybe I have to stop programming. I can't even do so simple things heh?

Comment: @user1939432 Don't be frustrated. Things take time.

Comment: @user1939432 if you only need to find out the / and % of two numbers, why do you ask for the 3rd number and try to do operations on it?

Comment: 3rd number is the number which digits will be separated.

Comment: if(temp>=divisor){
       
 if (quotient(temp,divisor))
 printf("%d  ", quotient(temp,divisor));                        else printf("0  ");    //I check if it is zero by this but this does not work also

Comment: @user1939432 see my post below? Does it solve your question, I think you are almost there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your information:  The 3rd number has nothing to do with quotient and remainder. You can simply separate the digits of a number from left to right as follows:
(PS. I am assuming that given 6900 you expect to see 6,9,0,0)

```
 #include <iostream>
 void getDigits(int number)
{
    int div = 1;
    //find max divisor, i.e., given 6900, divisor 1000
    //this gives information about how may digits the number has
    while (number / div >= 10) {
      div *= 10;
    } 

    //extract digits from left to right
    while (div != 0) //^^pay attention to this condition, not number !=0
    {
        int currDigit = number /div;
        number %= div;  
           //^^you can change the above two lines to 
          //your quotient and remainder function calls
        div /=10;
        std::cout << currDigit << " "; 
    }
}

int main(){
    int number = 6900;
    std::cout << "test case 1 " <<std::endl;
    getDigits(number);
    int number1 = 5067;
    std::cout << "\ntest case 2 " <<std::endl;
    getDigits(number1);
    int number2 = 12345;
    std::cout << "\ntest case 3 " <<std::endl;
    std::getDigits(number2);
    return 0;
}
```

Don't use `getch()`, which is deprecated. With the above code, you can see the following output:

```
test case 1
6 9 0 0
test case 2
5 0 6 7
test case 3
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Thanks so much I have to add digit count also. This seems like a puzzle

Comment: @user1939432 you mean count how many digits appears in a number? This is actually simple: there are at most 10 different digits (if you mean arabic numbers), so maintain an array of size 10, during extraction process, once you see a 9, increment counter for 9, if you see a 3, increment counter for 3. Do you agree?

Comment: This programming thing is completely different than my previsous jobs. Can you imagine I can not solve this but my employers expect me to solve JDBC related things at work. Ridiculous

Comment: @user1939432 we collect experience through doing different projects, so be positive and you will be there finally. We all go through these.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are not considering the cases where temp is less than the number and the divisor, i.e., the digit is a 0. For example, if the initial number is `302`, the divisor is `10` and temp is `2`, print out a `0`:

```
while (divisor > 0){
        if(temp>=divisor){
            printf("%d  ", quotient(temp,divisor));
            temp=remaindar(temp, divisor);
        } else if (temp < number) {
            printf("0 ");
        }
        divisor=divisor/10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  if(temp>=divisor) when this condition is true it bypasses else if below?